# azure python SDK retrieve backup items from recoverservices(backup)

Tags: python, azure, sdk, backup, azure-keyvault

I was told to move my bash script that reports on VM backup status, also reports VMs that are not being backed up to Azure automation account. I picked python since Automation Account doesn't have bash and I have done python scripts before for system admin purposes.  I am not a python developer, and I need help navigate Azure python SDK classes.

I need to find the "Backup Items" in portal from one of the python SDK modules, to retrieve the VM information from backup vault.  I've tried azure.mgmt.recoveryservices and azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup.  I can get vault information from azure.mgmt.recoveryservices, which I can use to query more information about vault, hopefully the VM information.  My guess is azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup.  But I am lost in azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup.jobs.models.  I can't tell among hundreds of classes, which one would give that information.

I'd like to use the output from vault backup to against the list of VMs, to find out which ones are not being backed up.

I've looked at:

- [activestamp Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup/azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup.activestamp?view=azure-python)
- [Azure SDK Releases](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/python.html)
- [Python Modules Related with azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup](https://www.programcreek.com/python/?ClassName=azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup&submit=Search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I was looking for is in "backup_protected_item", in RecoveryServicesBackupClient constructor, here is sample code.

```
from  azure.mgmt.recoveryservicesbackup import RecoveryServicesBackupClient

backup_items = backup_client.backup_protected_items.list(resource_group_name='rg_xxx', vault_name=var_vault)

print(backup_items.properties)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using python to get the backup of VM

You can use the below code snippet to get VM Backup details.

```py
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
import requests

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = '<Your Subscription ID>'
VM_NAME = '<VM Name>'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id='<Client id>',
    secret='<Client Secret>',
    tenant='<Your Tenent Id>'
)

# Creating base URL 
BASE_API_URL = "https://management.azure.com/Subscriptions/<Subscription>/resourceGroups/<Resourece group name>/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/your_vault_name/backupProtectedItems?api-version=2019-05-13&"

# Add the required filter to fetch the Exact details
customFilter="$filter=backupManagementType eq 'AzureIaasVM' and itemType eq 'VM' and policyName eq 'DailyPolicy'"

#Adding the Base API url with custom filter
BASE_URL = BASE_API_URL + customFilter

header = {
    "Authorization": 'Bearer '+ credentials.token["access_token"]
}

response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=header)

# here you can handle the response to know the details of backup
print(response.content)
...
```

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/quick-backup-vm-cli#monitor-the-backup-job) to achieve using Azure cli.